# Tests run perfectly on local machine but fails on azure devops

Tags: selenium, maven, devops, nosuchelementexception

using Maven Testng and Build is successful on Eclipse local machine but when the same was run on azure pipeline it shows error no such element and element not interactable

Comment: Hi Vivek, Can you pls take screenshot through selenium on failure pls. Also could you pls paste error message

Comment: Please go through : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.